How do I open and interpret the pho file from my DSO4104C HATEK oscilloscope?
I downloaded the .pho file from the DSO4104C HATEK oscilloscope yesterday, but I don't know how to open it. Please help.

According to Hantek, the .pho file represents the settings of the oscilloscope (rather than waveforms, or soup for that matter).
I would try opening it with a text editor such as notepad if you want to look at the contents. Maybe it's actually a .csv or .xml file. If it comes up as gibberish then it's probably a binary file.
